# How to get the most recent entry by two columns search in Spring boot's JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image: my database]

Could someone please help with querying the oldest entry with is id number 3 by customer id and eventType. Thank you

Comment: You mean the most recently created customer account? I'm asking because account with id 3 seems to be the youngest to me.

Comment: @Mihe right. The youngest one. Thank you

Comment: @Mihe partially. I want to get the last entry row by passing any of the field names, say email, id, etc. but I think this just gets the last entry which is very helpful. Is something like this allowed? findFirstByOrderByCustomerIdAndEventTypeDesc( String customerId, String eventType); Thank you

Comment: So, you want to get the most recent event of a set of events which are grouped by some properties/fields dynamically? I think you'll have to build your JPQL/SQL String (or CriteriaQuery) dynamically in that case.

Comment: @Mihe do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'd go with a native query like `SELECT * FROM events JOIN (SELECT field1, field2, max(create_date) created FROM events GROUP BY field1, field2) c ON events.field1 = c.field1 AND events.field2 = c.field2 AND  events.create_date = c.create_date`. Just build this query String programmatically and pass it to createNativeQuery() of the EntityManager.